# during accessibility testing, tools complain that my google search box is missing a title

Tags: html, wcag2.0

My google search box code

```
(function() {
var cx = 'x';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
  window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('gsc-i-id1').placeholder ='Search This Website'; 
    document.getElementById('gsc-i-id1').alt = 'website search';
 }
```

Waves tool warning is "Unlabled form element with title".  How can I get rid of this warning?

Answer (score 0):

`alt` is only valid for `<input type="image">`.  It would probably be satisfied if you used `aria-label="website search"`.

Comment: when i tried that, my entire search bar disappeared.

Comment: Adding an ARIA tag made content disappear?  I doubt that.

Comment: ok, maybe the aria-label is not a attribute of the gsc-i-id1 google bar?  where would you add aria-label, on the button element? i tried that as well and the error persists.  you say that the alt is for an image type which gsc-i-id1 element does have.

Comment: <img src="chrome-extension://jbbplnpkjmmeebjpijfedlgcdilocofh/img/icons/table_layout.png" class="wave5icon" tabindex="0" alt="STRUCTURAL ELEMENTS: Layout table" style="border: none; vertical-align: bottom; cursor: pointer; max-width: 44px; max-height: 25px; z-index: 10000; display: inline-block;">